# Which message passing method is suitable if a value need to be passed between many objects?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, message-passing

So I have a scenario where a value `id` need to be passed between different objects but instantiation of each objects is in hierarchical order.

For example:

```
ObjA 
  - Gets and id from web service
  Instantiate ObjB - (Obj A passes id to Obj B while instantiating)
     - Obj B instantiates Obj C (Obj B passes id to Obj C while instantiating)
```

And it goes on to 5-6 level of message passing and hierarchical object instantiation.

But message passing between objects while instantiating seems redundant. So I am thinking would it be better if I make an singleton class and every objects access the same value in a singleton? Or is there better way?

Comment: You could also think of it as a context (the data in the objects being in the context of that id). Then you could have some container type with the id and the related messages stored in it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. I would be grateful if you can show me some code sample. :)

Comment: Singleton is an anti-pattern. It makes code untestable, and prevents multi-threading. Passing the ID (or a context object containing the ID) is fine.

Comment: Since we are passing same value in every object down in hierarchy. wouldn't it be too cumbersome to pass values through context object or id if there is 5-6 levels of hierarchy of objects?

Comment: Also only top level object (object a) will set the id others will only get it

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha Don't worry. Happens to me a lot ;) Here the example code... obviously your sub-objects have something in common... instead of doing the pass-along you can as well treat them as an aggregate: `` data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: String }
data Bar = Bar { x :: Int, y :: Int }
data Context = Context { contextId :: Int, foo :: Foo, bar :: Bar }
init id foo bar = Context { contextId = id, foo = foo, bar = bar }``

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all your objects could extend a common interface. lets say

```
Interface SomeObject{}
```

Now at the top most layer, you can create a List

```
final List<SomeObject> objects = Arrays.asList(new Object1(), new Object2() and so on);
```

Now when you get the ID, you can run (using this list will also maintain the order of setting Ids if that is important.

```
for(SomeObject obj: objects){
    obj.setId(ID);
}
```

or you could use a stream to get it done in fewer lines of code.